# Asymptotic stochastic ordering for weighted sum of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, st.statistics

Are you aware of any literature focusing on the conditions such that for two i.i.d. sequences of discrete r.v.'s $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$,
\begin{equation}
a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\ldots+a_nX_n\geq_1 a_1Y_1+a_2Y_2+\ldots+a_nY_n
\end{equation}
holds for large enough $n$? "$\geq_1$" denotes first order stochastic dominance.

(something other than the trivial condition where $a_iX_i\geq_1a_iY_i,\ \forall i$.)

In particular, let $\{Y_n\}$ denote a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables ($\in\{1,-1\}$) with parameter $p\in(0,1)$, and $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+c}$ for some $c\in(0,1)$. Let $X_n\triangleq 2-Y_n$. Can we have the following dominance for large enough $n$?
\begin{equation}
a_{-n}X_{-n}\ldots+a_{-1}X_{-1}+a_1X_1+\ldots+a_nX_n\geq_1 a_{-n}Y_{-n}\ldots+a_{-1}Y_{-1}+a_1Y_1+\ldots+a_nY_n
\end{equation}

Comment: I imagine one can study the problem of the weighted random walk being nonnegative $S_{N}=\sum a_{k} Z_{k}\geq 0$ for $Z_{k}=X_{k}-Y_{k}$.

Comment: Are the $Y_k$'s symmetrically distributed?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Not in general. $Pr(Y_n=1)=1-Pr(Y_n=-1)=p\in(0,1)$

Comment: @ThomasKojar That probability does not converge to 1, does it?

Comment: @Ben Well it depends on the distribution of the X,Y and coefficients ak but yes I imagine so since X-Y has mean zero. But the point is that this problem has been studied a lot using hitting times i.e. weighted random walk hitting line. So you can try to get exact estimates on the probability of having $S_{n}\geq 0$.

Comment: @ThomasKojar I am still thinking of how to connect this stochastic dominance to the weighted random walk hitting lines. Are you suggesting to use a special coupling for this problem and show $Pr\{a_1X_1+....\geq a_1Y_1+....\}$ converge to 1?

Comment: @Ben My guess is that since $X-Y$ have mean zero, the random walk will not be above 0 eventually i.e. $Sn\geq 0$ will not converge to probability 1. It seems you will need to have some drift term for this to be true in the limit (positively-drifted Brownian motion diverges to plus infinity).